# Iterate through selected/active range

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to loop through a selected range and edit if a condition is met. Using code from here: https://yagisanatode.com/2017/12/13/google-apps-script-iterating-through-ranges-in-sheets-the-right-and-wrong-way/, I have the following:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var selectedRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
var lastColumn = selectedRange.getWidth();
var lastRow = selectedRange.getHeight();
var firstRow = selectedRange.getRow();
var firstColumn = selectedRange.getColumn();

function mySelectedRange() {

  var rangeValues = selectedRange.getValues();

  for ( i = firstColumn; i < lastColumn+1; i++){
    for ( j = firstRow ; j < lastRow; j++){
      Logger.log(sheet.getRange(j, i).getA1Notation());
      if(rangeValues[j][i] === "-"){
        sheet.getRange(j,i).setBackground("#cc4125");
      }else if (rangeValues[j][i] === 0){
        sheet.getRange(j,i).setBackground("#e69138");
      }; 
    };
  };
 
};
```

This is selected the right cell values, but does not change the background of the right cells. I tried this:

```
      if(rangeValues[j][i] === "-"){
        sheet.getRange(firstRow+j,firstColumn+i).setBackground("#cc4125");
      }else if (rangeValues[j][i] === 0){
        sheet.getRange(firstRow+j,firstColumn+i).setBackground("#e69138");
```

in order to select the correct cells but this does not pick up all cells.

How do I correctly loop through an arbitrary range to query a cell value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue:**

The issue with your approach is that `i = firstColumn; i < lastColumn` starts from the first column which can be `4` for example until the width of the range which might be `2`. Therefore, the `for` loop is ignored because the starting `j` is larger than the top value condition. The same issue holds true for the rows.

**Solution:**

Use:

`i = firstColumn; i < firstColumn+lastColumn` and `j = firstRow ; j < firstRow+lastRow` instead.

and then consider:

`rangeValues[j-firstRow][i-firstColumn]`

```
function selectedRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  const lastColumn = activeRange.getWidth();
  const lastRow = activeRange.getHeight();
  const firstRow = activeRange.getRow();
  const firstColumn = activeRange.getColumn();
  const rangeValues = activeRange.getValues();  
  for ( let i = firstColumn; i < firstColumn+lastColumn; i++){
    for ( let j = firstRow ; j < firstRow+lastRow; j++){
      let irange = sheet.getRange(j,i)
      if(rangeValues[j-firstRow][i-firstColumn] === "-"){
        irange.setBackground("#cc4125");
      }else if (rangeValues[j-firstRow][i-firstColumn] === 0){
        irange.setBackground("#e69138");
      }; 
    };
  };
};
```